# Show that $|x^2-4|\lt \epsilon$ when $0<|x-2|<\epsilon(5+\epsilon)^{-1}$

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods

I recently had to do a problem with the following part:

> Show that
>
> $|x^2-4|\lt \epsilon$
>
> when
>
> $0<|x-2|<\epsilon(5+\epsilon)^{-1}$

I couldn't figure out a solution to this. Any tips?

The source is Kincaid, D., & Cheney, W. Numerical Analysis: Mathematics of Scientific Computing. 2002.

Comment: @SubhajitGhosh I disagree.  $$x^2 = 4 + \frac{4\epsilon}{2(5 + \epsilon)} + \left[\frac{\epsilon}{2(5 + \epsilon)}\right]^2.$$ So $$x^2 - 4 = \frac{2\epsilon}{5 + \epsilon} + \left[\frac{\epsilon}{2(5 + \epsilon)}\right]^2 < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Sorry I did a calculation mistake. Thanks, @user2661923.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if my method is the most efficient way, but this will get the job done.
$$
|x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5+\epsilon} \,\Rightarrow\, |x+2| \le |x-2|+4 < \frac{\epsilon}{5+\epsilon} + 4
$$
So
\begin{align}
|x^2-4| 
&= |x-2||x+2|\\
&< \left(\frac{\epsilon}{5+\epsilon}\right)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{5+\epsilon} + 4\right) \\
&= \frac{5 \epsilon(\epsilon+4)}{(\epsilon +5)^2} \\
&= \frac{5}{\epsilon+5}\frac{\epsilon+4}{\epsilon+5} \epsilon\\
&< \epsilon
\end{align}

The last inequality is because the numerators are smaller than denominators so the fraction is less than $1$.